# Cambio en el significado de "acribia"

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

La palabra [**acribia**](https://dle.rae.es/acribia) aparece definido en el Diccionario de la lengua como:

> 1. f. cult. Exactitud, minuciosidad.

De acuerdo con el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) de la RAE, el término parece que fue introducido en el DLE en la edición de 2001 con esa misma definición.

Sin embargo, la consulta del [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) muestra que, aunque ausente en los diccionarios de la RAE, si aparecía en los diccionarios de Dominguez (1853 y 1869), Zerolo (1895), Alemany y Bolufer (1917) y Rodríguez Navas (1918) con un significado muy diferente:

> s.f. Arquit. Formación de contornos perfectos con el compás. || Exámen profundo.

¿Cómo se produjo ese cambio de significado? ¿Cómo tardó tanto (~150 años) en ser incluido en el DLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soy de España y esta palabra según he preguntado a mis padres se ha usado desde siempre, aunque su uso no ha sido muy popular, es de castellano antiguo.

Las palabras del DLE son introducidas por votación de un jurado de la RAE cada año. Hay muchas palabras estúpidas y olvidadas que se añaden al DLE y salen en las noticias, así que supongo que fue para hacer más interesante la edición de ese año.

No es un cambio completo de significado, para el compás se necesita exactitud, simplemente que como hoy en día se usan menos los compases esta palabra ha dejado de estar asociada exclusivamente a esta herramienta.

Comment: No entiendo con que parte de mi respuesta estas en desacuerdo, ni que tiene que ver con mi respuesta tu primer comentario... Simplemente he dado mi explicación como español a tus preguntas.

Comment: Vale ya veo a donde quieres llegar, los autores siempre han usado esta palabra desde siempre, se ve que como ha continuado su uso por autores hasta la actualidad han decidido meterla en la RAE, aunque ya te digo que cada año se meten palabras que se han usado desde siempre por cumplir el cupo.